# Getting info for multiple channels using usernames? (YT Data API v3) (PHP)

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm using the YouTube Data API v3 to get some basic information about some YouTube channels (thumbnail, title etc.), but I'm having some trouble with getting info for more than one channel. This is the request I'm using:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&forUsername={$user}&key={$key}"
```

I know I can use comma-separated `id`'s instead of `forUsername` but I want to avoid ID's as it's for a client's WordPress site. I want them to just be able to enter usernames if possible as ID's are difficult to find without looking in a channels source code.

This is the function I'm using:

```
function getYTChannelInfo($user) {
    $key = "MY_API_KEY";

    function fetchData($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }

    $result = fetchData("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&forUsername={$user}&key={$key}");
    $result = json_decode($result, true);
    return $result;
}
```

I've tried just calling the function multiple times (once for each channel) but that throws the error `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare fetchData()`.

What would be the best way to go about this? I'll use ID's if I absolutely have to but I thought I'd see if anyone here could come up with a solution.

Thanks,
Oli